# How to strip dashes out of file basename and display using php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to list links to all the files in a folder on my web site by including the code below in the index page in that folder.

Using this code outputs file names that look like this `name-of-file` which are linked to `name-of-file.html`.

Now how do I modify the code below to strip out the slashes and display the file names as `name of file`?

I'm a php noob so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $files = glob("*.html");
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            echo '<li><a href="'.basename($file).'">'.basename($file, ".html").'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_replace()`

```
<ul>
<?php
$files = glob("*.html");
foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '<li><a href="'.basename($file).'">'.str_replace('-', ' ', basename($file, ".html")).'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```